# Excel on how to get the total of the highest 4 marks totaled if their is 5 columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to get the total of the highest 4 values from a row in excel (if it has 5 marks allocated).

It is for marks awarded in Horse jumping.

5 People judge the event but only the 4 best mark need to be added, how can I do this.?

```
Mark 1  Mark 2  Mark 3  Mark 4  Mark 5      
 7        4       5      7       3      Total of only 4 highest marks
```

Answer (score 2):

This sums the largest four numbers in the range:

```
=SUM(LARGE(A2:E2,{1,2,3,4}))
```

Comment: What a great answer, although I'm lost why the need to 'hit' CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER

Comment: @Dave Good call. The formula takes an array but it is not an array formula, so no need for CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER

Comment: Just so you know, I didn't need that. I've copied your answer, pasted it in to my Excel as I normally would  and it worked fine with just hitting enter...

Answer (score 0):

While @Calvin's answer probably works, `=sum(a2:e2)-min(a2:e2)` seems a lot simpler to me.